# How to print multiple value column in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have a SQL Server database about `Customer` information and `CustomerPhone` has a multiple values column which is `C_Phone`.

This is my code:

```
if (!empty($_GET['customer_id'])){
    // 'id' input from the user
    $id = $_GET['customer_id'];
    // Customer Information
    $sql = "SELECT Customer.C_Code, C_FirstName, C_LastName, C_Email, C_HomeAddress, C_OfficeAddress, C_Phone
            FROM Customer, CustomerPhone
            WHERE Customer.C_code = CustomerPhone.C_code and Customer.C_code = $id;";
    $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query);
    if (!empty($row)) {
        echo "
        <div class=\"card\" style=\"width: 25rem; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;\">
            <div class=\"card-body\">
                <h5 class=\"card-title\">Customer Information</h5>";
        echo "<p class=\"card-text\">C_code: " . $row['C_Code'] . "</p>";
        echo "<p class=\"card-text\">C_Name: " . $row['C_FirstName'] . " " . $row['C_LastName'] . "</p>";
        echo "<p class=\"card-text\">C_Email: " . $row['C_Email'] . "</p>";
        echo "<p class=\"card-text\">C_HomeAddress: " . $row['C_HomeAddress'] . "</p>";
        echo "<p class=\"card-text\">C_OfficeAddress: " . $row['C_OfficeAddress'] . "</p>";
        echo "<p class=\"card-text\">C_Phone: ";
        while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
        {   
            echo $row['C_Phone'] . "<br>";
        }
        echo "</p>";
        echo "
            </div>
        </div>";
    }
```

This is the result I got. How can I print the second phone number under the first one?
[image]

If I run the SQL query above on the SSMS, I got this result with `Customer.C_Code = 7`:

[image]

Comment: *Major thing* - Your code is vulnerable to sql injection. Use prepared statements any time a variable needs to be put into a query. *Minor thing* - “a multiple values column” is incorrect. What you have is a one-to-many relationship. There’s a huge difference between the two; the former being a nightmare and the latter being correct. It looks like your tables are correct, fortunately. Had you used `while ($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array)` instead of an `if`, you would have gotten both rows.  To get your desired result, you must either use nested queries or use aggregate functions in your sql.

Comment: @TimMorton thanks for point out the SQL injection problem in my code, I didn't notice that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this unexpected behaviour is that you need to echo the customer phone from the first fetched row (`echo "<p class=\"card-text\">C_Phone: ". $row['C_Phone'] . "<br>";` instead of `echo "<p class=\"card-text\">C_Phone: ";`).

You may also consider the following:

- Use explicit `JOIN` syntax.
- Use parameterized queries. As is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-query?view=sql-server-ver15), *the sqlsrv_query function is well-suited for one-time queries and should be the default choice to execute queries unless special circumstances apply and sqlsrv_query function does both statement preparation and statement execution, and can be used to execute parameterized queries*.

The following example, based on your code, is a possible solution to your problem:

```
if (!empty($_GET['customer_id'])) { 
    // Customer Information
    $sql = "
        SELECT c.C_Code, c.C_FirstName, c.C_LastName, c.C_Email, c.C_HomeAddress, c.C_OfficeAddress, p.C_Phone
        FROM Customer c
        JOIN CustomerPhone p ON c.C_code = p.C_code
        WHERE c.C_code = ?;
    ";
    $params = array($_GET['customer_id']);
    $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
    if ($query === false) {
        echo "Error (sqlsrv_query): ".print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
        exit;
    }   
    // fetch data
    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query);
    if (!empty($row)) {
        echo "
        <div class=\"card\" style=\"width: 25rem; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;\">
            <div class=\"card-body\">
                <h5 class=\"card-title\">Customer Information</h5>";
        echo "<p class=\"card-text\">C_code: " . $row['C_Code'] . "</p>";
        echo "<p class=\"card-text\">C_Name: " . $row['C_FirstName'] . " " . $row['C_LastName'] . "</p>";
        echo "<p class=\"card-text\">C_Email: " . $row['C_Email'] . "</p>";
        echo "<p class=\"card-text\">C_HomeAddress: " . $row['C_HomeAddress'] . "</p>";
        echo "<p class=\"card-text\">C_OfficeAddress: " . $row['C_OfficeAddress'] . "</p>";
        echo "<p class=\"card-text\">C_Phone: ". $row['C_Phone'] . "<br>";
        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
        {   
            echo $row['C_Phone'] . "<br>";
        }
        echo "</p>";
        echo "
            </div>
        </div>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two routes you can take. You will have to adapt these ideas to your database connection functions, as I have no experience with microsoft databases

## Nested loops

In each iteration of the customer information, do a second query of CustomerPhone, using the C_code obtained from Customer. As mentioned in the comments, use a `while` statement to iterate through the results.

```
while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query) {
```

Care must be taken to prevent the inner query from clobbering the outer!

## SQL Aggregate functions

This involves making a more sophisticated query. You can `group by` a field and have the database concatenate fields:

```
SELECT 
     Customer.C_Code, C_FirstName, C_LastName, 
     C_Email, C_HomeAddress, C_OfficeAddress, 
     string_agg(C_Phone, ', ') AS phone
FROM Customer
INNER JOIN CustomerPhone ON Customer.C_code = CustomerPhone.C_code
WHERE
     Customer.C_code = ?
GROUP BY Customer.C_code
```

(note that some databases require every field used to be in the `group by` clause)

(note 2 - This is a parameterized query, to be used with a prepare command. see the documentation for prepared statements. This is the correct way to use values in a query)

As shown, this will list them as csv. You could also use `<br>` to separate them instead of a comma.